# Data is not being saved to Database

Tags: android, mongodb

In my android application I am trying to save some data in MongoDB database. I using this code (given below) for that. This code is displaying `Toast` that `data is saved`, but the data is not present in my database. I am not getting any exception. so kindly tell what can be the problem?

**Code:**

```
@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(String... reminder) {
    try {
        URL requestUrl = new URL("MongoDB address");
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) requestUrl.openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        connection.connect();
        OutputStream save = connection.getOutputStream();
        save.write(reminder[0].getBytes());
        save.close();
        connection.disconnect();

        new Handler(context.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(context, "data is saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
    catch(Exception exception) {
        Log.e("ERROR", "DB Saving", exception);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: paste you log please

Comment: Are you updating your database directly from the app? If this app is going to  be public that means anybody can access your database.